# ¿Cual es la funcion de refs en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo React quisiera saber la definion o cual es su uso de refs, tengo esta funcion dentro de un submit, que valor obtiene a partid de refs?

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let email = this.refs.email.value.trim();
    let password = this.refs.password.value.trim();

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Join Short Lnk</h1>

        {this.state.error ? <p>{this.state.error}</p> : undefined}

        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input type="email" ref="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="password" ref="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          <button>Create Account</button>
        </form>

        <Link to="/">Already have an account?</Link>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**refs**(referencias) son especialmente útiles cuando necesita encontrar el marcado DOM prestado por un componente (por ejemplo, para posicionarlo de forma absoluta).

El atributo ref es de tipo String.

React también admite el uso de una cadena (en lugar de una devolución de llamada) como referencia en cualquier componente.

Asigne un **ref** atributo a cualquier cosa devuelta **render** como:

```
<input ref="myInput" />
```

En algún otro código (típicamente código de controlador de eventos), acceda a la instancia de respaldo vía **this.refs** como en:

```
var input = this.refs.myInput;
var inputValue = input.value;
var inputRect = input.getBoundingClientRect();
```

**Refs** son una gran manera de enviar un mensaje a una instancia particular de un niño de una manera que sería inconveniente hacer a través de **streaming** **Reactive props**y **state**. Sin embargo, no deberían ser tu abstracción de ir a la información fluida a través de tu aplicación. De forma predeterminada, utilice el flujo de datos Reactivo y guárdelo refpara casos de uso que sean inherentemente no reactivos.

Comment: Gracias por la información, me quedo mas claro !